# Display HTML content in a new tab from global.html in Safari Extension

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

i am creating a safari extension in which i need to create a new tab and display some html content in it...i am able to open a new tab using

```
var newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab()`
```

but i am not able to set the html content...is there anyway i can do that

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can load a local HTML file (in the extension package, not the computer's file system) which might already contain the content you want.

```
var newTab = safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.openTab();
newTab.url = safari.extension.baseURI + 'example.html';
```

If you need to add content after loading the file, and the content to add resides in the context of the global page, you can use the messaging system to transmit the content to the page in the tab. See [this page](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW1) in the Safari Extension Development Guide.

Comment: i have already tried by opening a new tab and setting the url to the local file...but somehow the browser does not display the content in the new tab...any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have any ideas. It works for me. If your extension does not contain anything sensitive, you're welcome to email it to me and I'll take a look. canisbos[at]gmail[dot]com.